# [__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 9223372036854775807 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

When I try to run my app I get this error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 9223372036854775807 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
```

I really don't know what my error is. I also noticed that when I store a dateTime data in my table it is enclosed with parentheses and quotation like 9:47 am turns into ("9:47 am"). I'm really new to Xcode. I'm a week old at this. Here is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";

SimpleTableCell *cell = (SimpleTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
{
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SimpleTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
}

NSInteger indexOfAlarm = [self.dbManager.arrColumnNames indexOfObject:@"Time"];
   cell.timeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[self.arrAlarmInfo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectAtIndex:indexOfAlarm] ];
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The value of 9223372036854775807 is the constant `NSNotFound`. It signals that the instance searched for does not exists in the array. To check for it, add an `if`-statement:

```
NSInteger indexOfAlarm = [self.dbManager.arrColumnNames indexOfObject:@"Time"];
if(indexOfAlarm != NSNotFound) // <-
{
   cell.timeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[self.arrAlarmInfo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectAtIndex:indexOfAlarm] ];
}
return cell;
```

If you expect `@"Time"` to be always in the array, you have to find out, why it isn't there.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation Amin. I'm able to solve my problem with "@Time".

Answer (score -2):

**Change this code**

```
 NSInteger indexOfAlarm = [self.dbManager.arrColumnNames indexOfObject:@"Time"];

 cell.timeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[self.arrAlarmInfo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectAtIndex:indexOfAlarm] ];
```

**TO**

```
 NSNumber *indexOfAlarm = [self.dbManager.arrColumnNames indexOfObject:@"Time"];

 cell.timeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[self.arrAlarmInfo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectAtIndex:indexOfAlarm.intValue] ];
```

Comment: Have you referenced to the document? It says this `- (id)objectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index`